# In Excel, how do I locate a row, a column and a cell by referring to their names?

Tags: javascript, excel, data-driven-tests

### Background

I am working on a data-driven test suite, which uses an Excel file as its data source.

### Problem

The layout of this Excel sheet is:

```
TestName            FirstName    SecondName    Address
End_To_End_Test     Bruce        Wayne         Gothm
Age_Rule_Test       Alice        Chen          Wonderland
```

How do I locate **Bruce** by using **FirstName** as the column reference and **End_To_End_Test** as the row reference?

I have been looking for a function that does something like:

```
cell = Excel.ColumnIndex("FirstName").RowIndex("End_To_End_Test") //cell.value = "Bruce"
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you please leave a comment instead of simply voting down this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table starts in A1, you can find the:

Row: `=MATCH(A2,A:A,0)` (say in G1)
Column: `=MATCH(B1,1:1,0)` (say in G2)
Cell: `=ADDRESS(G2,G1)`
Cell content: `=INDEX(A1:D3, MATCH("End_To_End_Test",A:A,0), MATCH("FirstName",1:1,0))`

Answer (score 1):

so if you are trying to return the matching Firstname with the criteria "End_to_End_test" in the column Testname, this is how you do it:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$3,MATCH($F$7,$A$2:$A$3,0))
```

[image: index formula]

if you want to have a dynamic solution where you can change the references with dropdownlists, this is how you do it:

=INDEX($A$2:$D$3,MATCH($G$8,INDEX($A$2:$D$3,,MATCH($I$8,$A$1:$D$1,0)),0),MATCH($I$9,$A$1:$D$1,0))

[image: dynamic version]